# Auto-Populate multiple lookup fields using Custom Button

Tags: custom-button

I have created a custom button for cases, which is on the Opportunity page. I need multiple fields to be auto populated in the case when the user clicks on the button. I was able to make the opportunity to be populated, but having issues with populating additional fields. Any help?

Here is what the code looks at the moment:

> https://company.my.salesforce.com/500/e?CF00NA000000CI7aP={!Opportunity.Name}&CF00NA000000CI7aP_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&00NA000000CI7aP={!Opportunity.Id}
>   ,
>   https://company.my.salesforce.com/500/e?CF00NA000000CI7aZ={!Opportunity.Category_Name__c}&CF00NA000000CI7aZ_lkid={!Opportunity.Category_NameId__c}&00NA000000CI7aZ={!Opportunity.Category_NameId__c}

I don't get any error message, but only the opportunity is linked to the field in the case record. The category name doesn't get auto populated. What am I doing wrong? Do you not use "," to add addition auto populate commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL should be specified only once. All of the parameters should follow the "?" in a key=value&key2=value2 format.

> https://company.my.salesforce.com/500/e?CF00NA000000CI7aP={!Opportunity.Name}&CF00NA000000CI7aP_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&00NA000000CI7aP={!Opportunity.Id}&CF00NA000000CI7aZ={!Opportunity.Category_Name__c}&CF00NA000000CI7aZ_lkid={!Opportunity.Category_NameId__c}&00NA000000CI7aZ={!Opportunity.Category_NameId__c}

Also, make sure there's no unintended spaces, as that can cause errors.